# Python Vector Does Not Have Column Size? / Theta Initialized As All 0's

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

The outline of this assignment was given to me by my professor. It is building a linear regression model using gradient descent. My questions are:

1. How is the row vector initialized by the 
      theta = np.zeros(3)
   not a 1 x 3 matrix? The representation of this is [0,0,0]
2. Is there a way to get around the error I am getting? Shown below, but basically says I cannot subtract the two matrices because they are mismatched sizes.

For clarification, I cannot change the dimensions of theta.

Really looking for understanding on how this subtraction is supposed to work

```
def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters):
    '''
    Params
        X - Shape: (m,3); m is the number of data examples
        y - Shape: (m,)
        theta - Shape: (3,)
        num_iters - Maximum number of iterations
    Return
        A tuple: (theta, RSS, cost_array)
        theta - the learned model parameters
        RSS - residual sum of squares
        cost_array - stores the cost value of each iteration. Its shape is 
        (num_iters,)
    '''
    m = len(y)
    cost_array =[]

    for i in range(0, num_iters):
        #### START YOUR CODE ####
        # Make predictions
        # Shape of y_hat: m by 1
        y_hat = np.dot(X, theta)

        # Compute the difference between prediction (y_hat) and ground 
        truth label (y)
        diff = y_hat - y

        # Compute the cost
        # Hint: Use the diff computed above
        cost = np.sum((diff ** 2)/(2 * m))
        cost_array.append(cost)

        # Compute gradients
        # Hint: Use the diff computed above
        # Hint: Shape of gradients is the same as theta
        gradients = np.dot(np.transpose(X), diff) / m

        # Update theta
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient

        #### END YOUR CODE ####

    # Compute residuals
    # Hint: Should use the same code as Task 1
    #### START YOUR CODE ####
    y_hat = np.dot(X, theta)
    RSS = numpy.sum(numpy.square(y - y_hat))
    #### END YOUR CODE ####

    return theta, RSS, cost_array


# This cell is to evaluate the gradientDescent function implemented above

#### DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW ####
# Define learning rate and maximum iteration number
ALPHA = 0.05
MAX_ITER = 500

# Initialize theta to [0,0,0]
theta = np.zeros(3)
theta_method2, RSS2, cost_array = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, ALPHA, 
MAX_ITER)

print('Theta obtained from gradient descent:', theta_method2)
print('Residual sum of squares (RSS): ', RSS2)
```

ERROR BELOW

```
<ipython-input-24-9869b26dea76> in gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, 
num_iters)
     36 
     37         # Update theta
---> 38         theta = np.subtract(theta, (alpha * gradients))
     39 
     40         #### END YOUR CODE ####

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) 
(3,105)
```

Comment: `np.zeros(3)` has shape `(3,)`.  `zeros((1,3))` has shape `(1,3)`.

Comment: @hpaulj any suggestions as to how I can update theta ?

Comment: Looks like `theta` should be (3,1) shape.

Answer (score 1):

To change the shape of theta from (3,) to (1,3) you can do:

```
theta = np.expand_dims(theta, axis=0)  # Now theta.shape = (1,3)
```

However, I tried running your code with:

```
X = np.ones((10,3))
y = np.ones((10,))
```

as a test. I only changed the line with `theta = theta - alpha * gradient` to `theta = theta - alpha * gradients` (added an s at the end of gradients). This may have been causing problems because there is no `gradient` in the scope of this `gradientDescent` function.

This did not give an error.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I should have emphasized that I cannot change the dimensions of theta.

Comment: I actually don't think you need to change the dimensions of theta, I think you just need to add an 's' at the end of `gradient`